# System File Missing

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, restore, windows-sbs, windows

I have Windows SBS 2008 R2 use it as file server and i missing some system32 file, so i need to repair it but I don't  know how repair/restore this file.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Boot from the original setup disk. Select "Repair Windows". It will open a command prompt. From there enter:
`sfc /offbootdir=[boot drive path] /offwindire=[windows path]`
This command is commonly:
`sfc /offbootdir=C:\ /offwindire=C:\Windows`
This will scan for all files that are missing or corrupted and should fix them.

Comment: thanks for reply
i try to fix it by that command but i got this message 
"windows resource protection could not start the repair service"

note : i dont have backup for system

thanks

Comment: @Hossam: That error indicates that `sfc` was not started in offline mode (hence it's looking for a service that doesn't exist in offline). Make sure you entered the command as it appears (or with the drive letter changed where appropriate).